# How do I get random values in a list to be unique by at least a given amount by each value in the list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I'm fairly new to python.

I'm trying to make a list with unique random values that differ with every other random value in the list by at least a given factor and that are all bounded by two values.

For example, I want a list like:

```
randVals = [24, 418, 100, 286, 350]
```

where each value is unique by at least a given factor of 64 with each other.

Right now, my code:

```
import random

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
randVals = [0] * (len(x) + 1)
factor = 64

print(randVals)

for i in range(len(randVals) - 1):
    randVals[i] = random.randint(10, 502)

    while randVals[i + 1] - factor <= randVals[i] <= randVals[i + 1] + factor:
        randVals[i] = random.randint(10, 502)
    print(randVals)

randVals.pop(len(x))
    print(randVals)
```

outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[494, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[494, 144, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[494, 144, 489, 0, 0, 0]
[494, 144, 489, 342, 0, 0]
[494, 144, 489, 342, 361, 0]
[494, 144, 489, 342, 361]
```

Comment: What is your question? E.g are you trying to make your code more efficient, generate a specific distribution, etc.?

Comment: Also, do you need only the adjacent values to differ by `64` or all pairwise values to differ by `64`?

Comment: I'm trying to get all values to be between 10 and 502 while all the values in the list are at least 64 units apart or more.

Comment: You need to keep track of your last inserted value and then choose a random number between this last number + 64 and infinity (or some other max value)

Comment: This may not always be possible. What happens if you want 10 numbers and the first one you generated is 64, then to generate all 10 you need to get out of the range.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I was thinking because they're just random values, in the case that it does something like that, it would go back and change that value and maybe start the process over.

Comment: In the end you can only have `n = (502 - 10) // 64` different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make sure I understand what you're trying to do:
"I'm trying to make a list with unique random values that differ pairwise by at least a given factor and that are all bounded by two values."
"I'm trying to get all values to be between 10 and 502 while all the values in the list are at least 64 units apart or more."

Then, in keeping with your approach of using `random.randint`:

```
import random    # to generate random values

randVals = []    # and keep those values in a list
factor = 64      # values should differ by this factor
low = 10         # lower bound
high = 502       # upper bound

x = low     # start at lower bound

length = 8  # list should be of this length

if(high - factor*length)<low:
    print('Impossible to generate list with given parameters')
else:
    for i in range(length):

        # generate a random integer, leaving space
        # for enough others given the various requirements...
        randVal = random.randint(x, high-factor*(length-i))

        # add to list
        randVals.append(randVal)
        x = randVal + factor


    print(randVals)    

    # if we want, we can shuffle the list
    random.shuffle(randVals)
    print(randVals)
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it doesn't append once the 2nd x value it finds is smaller than the first. Often occurring with a list with less than 5 values.

Comment: The values increase in size, because `x` is reassigned at the end of each `while` loop: `x = randVal + factor`; so the 2nd x value is never smaller than the first.

Comment: Maybe try to get a random number between `x` and `x + high`

Comment: if you don't want them ordered, we can shuffle them: `random.shuffle(randVals)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I meant by pairwise also. I'm trying to make sure in a list of "5" values, every value inside is different by at least 64.

Comment: @Charuka -- ah, you also want to specify the length of your list...

Comment: @PeterPrescott I was just testing it, and it works perfectly for what I require, however, if I try to change the length to 8 or above, I'm getting a ValueError: empty range for randrange() (10, -9, -19)

Comment: 8 * 64 is 512. And you're trying to fit your list between 10 and 502...

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
from random import sample


def random_list(spacing, k=5, lo=10, hi=502):
    return sample(list(range(lo, hi+1, spacing)), k=k)


result = random_list(64, k=5)

print(result)
```

**Output** *(random)*

```
[10, 458, 394, 266, 330]
```

With `list(range(lo, hi+1, spacing))` you generate all the numbers between 10 and 502 with a step of 64, then use [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to randomly select `k` numbers from that population.

Comment: but in this case all of the numbers you generate are equal `mod 64`, which I wouldn't characterize as exactly "random"